# How to add numbers in an array while skipping ones that have already been added?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that takes a "target number" and other numbers from a .txt file, and needs to write a new .txt file that says which  two numbers sum up to the target number.

I used a vector array to take in all the numbers in the file they give. The target number in one file was 13, and the numbers that I need to determine if it can add up to 13 were 5 12 8 10 7 4 3 5 5 3 2 1. I've managed to get the program to work, but as you can see, the list of numbers has multiple "5's", so it keeps repeating, "8 + 5 = 13" "5 + 8 = 13" multiple times.

```
vector<int> numbers;
int currentInt;
while (inFile >> currentInt) {
    numbers.push_back(currentInt);
}
int length = numbers.size();
outfile << target << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target) {
            outFile << "Yes" << endl;
            if (i == j) {
                outFile << numbers[i] << "*2=" << target << endl;
            }
            else {
                outFile << numbers[i] << "+" << numbers[j] << "=" << target << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << "The new created file will contain the doubles and sums        leading to the target number" << endl;
inFile.close();
outFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

The expected output should be:

```
13                        // the target number
5 12 8 10 7 4 3 5 5 3 2 1 // the numbers that can sum up to 13
Yes                       // declaring that there are 2 numbers that add up to 13
5+8=13                    // saying which numbers add up to 13
```

What outputs for me:

```
13
Yes
5+8=13
Yes
12+1=13
Yes
8+5=13
Yes
8+5=13
Yes
8+5=13
Yes
10+3=13
Yes
10+3=13
Yes
3+10=13
Yes
5+8=13
Yes
5+8=13
Yes
3+10=13
Yes
1+12=13
```

Comment: You could use a `std::set`.

Comment: Yes, use a `std::set` (or a `std::unordered_set`) and then convert that to a `std::vector` when you've finished.

Comment: Why don't you just `break;` inside `if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target) {`?

Comment: @DimChtz: It can’t just be one `break;`, but that’s the right direction.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yeah 2 for loops. Still can do the same without `break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything else works, you can just exit both for loops as soon as you find your first set of numbers:

```
vector<int> numbers;
int currentInt;
while (inFile >> currentInt) {
    numbers.push_back(currentInt);
}
int length = numbers.size();
outfile << target << endl;

bool done = false;
for (int i = 0; i < length && !done; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target) {
            outFile << "Yes" << endl;
            if (i == j) {
                outFile << numbers[i] << "*2=" << target << endl;
            }
            else {
                outFile << numbers[i] << "+" << numbers[j] << "=" << target << endl;
            }

            done = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cout << "The new created file will contain the doubles and sums        leading to the target number" << endl;
inFile.close();
outFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that, but I figured I was supposed to show all the possible solutions but I think the only way to do this properly is show just the first solution and just end the program. Thanks to everyone that helped.